# How to make vertical auto scrolling image inside div?

Tags: javascript

I need auto scrolling image placed inside a div. I saw a code for horizontal auto scroll on this page
http://www.dynamicsights.com/cssscrollback.php
I modified it a little to turn it into vertical auto scroll, but for some reason it stopped working. Can someone please tell me what I did wrong, and is there easier way to make vertical auto scroll?

```
<div id="scroller"></div>
```

css:

```
#scroller
{
width:250px; height:120px;
background-image:url(images/background.png); /* size of that image is 250x600 */
}
```

js:

```
function StartMove()
{
var BGImage = new Image();
BGImage.src = "images/background.png";
window.cssMaxHeight = 600;
window.cssYPos = 0;
setInterval("MoveBackGround()", 50);
}

function MoveBackGround()
{
window.cssYPos ++;
if (window.cssYPos >= window.cssMaxHeight)
  {
  clearInterval(MoveBackGround())
  }
toMove=document.getElementById("scroller");
toMove.style.backgroundPosition="0 "+window.cssYPos+"px";
}
```

Comment: clearInterval(MoveBackGround())  <-- not right

Comment: How do I stop StartMove() function once the image scrolls down to the bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code has so many global variables and removing the interval is wrong.

```
(function() {
    var cssMaxHeight, cssYPos, interval, moveTo;

    function MoveBackGround() {
        cssYPos++;        
        if (cssYPos >= cssMaxHeight) {
            window.clearInterval(interval);
        }
        toMove = document.getElementById("scroller");
        toMove.style.backgroundPosition = "0 " + cssYPos + "px";
    }

    function StartMove() {
        var BGImage = new Image();
        BGImage.src = "images/background.png";
        cssMaxHeight = 600;
        cssYPos = 0;
        interval = setInterval(MoveBackGround, 50);
    }

    StartMove();

}());
```